# C# ASP.NET crystal reports on server/hosting

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, crystal-reports, report

I need some help about displaying crystal report on server/hosting, I created account on some free hosting just to check how does my application work when it's UP and not on localhost as allways, and I've found out my crystal reports are not working on web (THEY ARE NOT DISPLAYED, PAGE WHERE I AM CALLING REPORT IS OPENING BUT ITS BLANK - WHITE ) ..

Before when I used to test it on localhost I had similar issue, so I copyed **aspnet_client folder** to my project folder and I solved error on localhost, but what now when its UP on hosting? I guess I have to do something like I did on localhost but I dont know exactly what..

Thank you guys, I will appreciate any kind of help

Comment: Can you post the code that you have tried and the resources that you have looked at?

Comment: Yes I can post code, but my code is working because when I am testing application on localhost-from visual studio everything is fine after i copied aspnet_client to my project folder, so code is ok :-) but when I publish application my report is not loading, its opening blank page :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I FINALLY SOLVED THIS, AND HERE IS HOW:

FIRST OF ALL DO THE FOLLOWING: AFTER YOUR BLANK PAGE LOADS, GO TO INSPECT PAGE AND FIND CONSOLE ERROR, IN MY EXAMPLE I SAW THAT MY APPLICATION IS LOOKING FOR FOLDER WITH NAME 4_6_1069/crystalreportviewer13 etc..  AND WITH SOME OTHER FILES, SO I MANUALLY CREATE THAT FOLDER ON MY SERVER/HOSTING, AND I COPIED FILES FROM EXISTING FOLDERS ON THIS PATH **aspnet_client/system_web/*FOLDERSTHATINEED*** to my new created folder "4_6_1069".. and that's it

:)

Comment: Yes I am sure, because it works, I did not install anything on server, I just installed crystal reports on my local machine, created publish, published project, created missing folder manually and copied files from existing folder with folder that my app is looking for and everything went fine

Comment: I am using public hosting, I took trial account for 3 months just for testing purposes :)